# How to format data labels with Jquery Highcharttable column charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts

Currently my data labels will appear in the columns contained within my column chart. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to possibly change the positioning of these labels. I was thinking it would be done somewhat like this but I can't get anything to change. I have the colors changing but cannot get the data labels to change position.

It currently looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN6SS.jpg

```
$('#hidden-highchart-table').bind('highchartTable.beforeRender', function (event, highChartConfig) {
                highChartConfig.colors = ['#6d9dd2', '#6fb1b8', '#6d8547', '#eea032', '#ba3c3c',   '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'];
                highChartConfig.dataLabels = {
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                y: 45};
            }).highchartTable();
```

Comment: The datalables are not printed aboce column, because there is not enough space. Try to increase [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) or use [crop](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels.crop) / [overflow](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels.overflow) options.

Comment: @SebastianBochan ok thank you I will try that, I figured it was probably a lack of space near the top of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

dataLables is in plotOptions.series not at the top level.  So, you should be setting:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                verticalAlign:'top'
            }
        }
    },
```

I don't know what the rest of your highChartConfig looks like, so you want to make sure you aren't overwriting the entire plotOpions object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I ended up figuring out how to fix this issue. You can access the dataLabels object using the Jquery HighChart Tables plugin by utilizing this function.

```
$('#hidden-highchart-table').bind('highchartTable.beforeRender', function (event, highChartConfig) {
            highChartConfig.plotOptions.series.dataLabels = {blah: blah, blah2: blah2}; 
        }).highchartTable();
```

Within this function you can do any of the customization that is done in the normal Highcharts API just the syntax is slightly different on how you access the objects and their properties.